# What are the "success" and "failure" vibration patterns in Apple Watch, and iPhone 7 haptic?

Tags: iphone, apple, wearables

I want to imitate the Apple Watch  "success" and "failure" vibration patterns in my custom app.

Does anyone have the following information for the various user experiences

- Intensity
- Timing
- Pattern
- (direction?)
- ???

Comment: As an aside, I am interested in designing a set of vibration patters for non-visual interactions. I am not aware of any published material to date but will be watching the question very closely.

Comment: [This article](http://www.sneakycrab.com/blog/2015/6/22/haptic-feedback-with-the-taptic-engine-in-watchkit-and-watchos-2-wkinterfacedevice-and-wkhaptic) seems to have the pattern (success = "tap,tap,tap", failure = "long vibration")

Answer (score 1):

In watchOS Human Interface Guidelines apple provide audio of "success" and "failure" vibration. https://developer.apple.com/watchos/human-interface-guidelines/interactions/#haptic-feedback

Apple watch use hardware they call taptic engine. Vibration is generated by **linear** repeating moving.

[image]

(gif source: www.ifixit.com)

Answer (score 0):

Standard [haptic feedback](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/feedback/) patterns are now exposed in iOS 10.  Here are some examples in C#/Xamarin

```
    #region Override Methods
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    #endregion

    #region Custom Actions
    partial void ImpactAction(Foundation.NSObject sender)
    {
        // Initialize feedback
        var impact = new UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(UIImpactFeedbackStyle.Heavy);
        impact.Prepare();

        // Trigger feedback
        impact.ImpactOccurred();
    }

    partial void NotificationAction(Foundation.NSObject sender)
    {
        // Initialize feedback
        var notification = new UINotificationFeedbackGenerator();
        notification.Prepare();

        // Trigger feedback
        notification.NotificationOccurred(UINotificationFeedbackType.Error);
    }

    partial void SelectionAction(Foundation.NSObject sender)
    {
        // Initialize feedback
        var selection = new UISelectionFeedbackGenerator();
        selection.Prepare();

        // Trigger feedback
        selection.SelectionChanged();
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: As this is the UX stackexchange, I think an answer that doesn't rely on code snippets would be more appropriate. The question is less "how do I implement", and more "what characteristics of vibration patterns best relay 'success' or 'failure'"